# How to connect to Cassandra using FluentCassandra

Tags: cassandra, fluentcassandra

I am new to Cassandra and FluentCassandra.

In a real environment: we will have Cassandra installed in all the nodes(multiple servers).

```
using (var db = new CassandraContext(keyspace: KeyspaceName, server: Server))
```

In this situation what should be mentioned as server name?

Answer (score 0):

Just mention multiple server host address along with their port number.